# SQL Server Stress Test Tools?

Tags: sql-server, stress-testing

I am looking for a stress tool for SQL Server. I've seen a lot of suggestions on Google. But nothing of what I really need.

I am really looking for a tool that could run a list of stored procedures in parallel to see how much contention on resources. The collect and reporting feature is not that important. But I also want something server-side base for our enterprise build server.

I am not looking for a replay feature (Yes it could do the trick but it would be difficult to program a lot of different scenarios)

I've look at the following tools:

- RML Utilities from Microsoft
- DTM DB Stress (this is the closest to what I'm looking for)
- SQL Stress

Comment: How much data do you expect, number of new rows per day, number of users etc? Why not just go for it and see what happens? A stress test won't replicate *true* server load...

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple test tool for this scenario, check it out to see if it will be of any use to you. It's free, no licensing of any sort required. No guarantees on any performance or quality either ;-)

Usage: StressDb.exe <No. of instances> <Tot. Runtime (mins)> <Interval (secs)>
Connection string should reside in the configuration file.
All command line arguments are required. Use integers.
The stored proc to use is also in the config file.

You need to have .NET framework 3.5 installed. You can also run it from multiple workstations for additional load, or from multiple folders on same machine if trying to run additional stored procedures. You also need a SQL user Id, as currently it doesn't use a trusted connection.

This code was actually super simple, the only clever bit was making sure that the connections are not pooled.

http://......com/..../stressdb.zip

Let me know if you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I am looking for something more "enterprise" with licensing and support. The program you supplied might do the trick but I would need to collect a lot of different tools together to generate reports and analyze data. I found a lot of tools to stress client application but no a lot to stress the data tier.